# Как правильно обратиться к членам другого класса?

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть класс `TFigure` который должен обратиться к своим потомкам `TRectangle` и `TTriangle` за переменными `ry1`, `rx3` и `txN`, `tyN`(где `N` - число от 1 до 3, определяющее пару точек.)
Нужно из класса TFigure методом IsIntersect обратиться к классам TTriangle и TRectangle за координатами точек для обработки через блок условий.
Коды:

TFigure.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TFigure.h"
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

TFigure::TFigure()
{
StepX = 0;
StepY = 0;
}


TFigure::~TFigure()
{

}

void TFigure::Move()
{
}

void TFigure::IsIntersect()
{
//for (int iy = ry1; iy < ry3; iy++) // переменная ry1 И ry3 определена в классе TRectangle. Как дать знать классу TFigure про их существование и чему они равны?
//{

//}
}
```

TRectangle.cpp

```
...
TRectangle::TRectangle()
{
rx1 = 0;  //    x1,y1              x2,y2
ry1 = 0;  //    x3,y3              x4,y4
rx2 = 10;
ry2 = 0;
rx3 = 0;
ry3 = 4;
rx4 = 10;
ry4 = 4;
//  rStepX = 0;
//  rStepY = 0;
}


TRectangle::~TRectangle()
{
}
...
```

Comment: "N число от 1 до 3 определяющее пару точек" - пару чисел?

Comment: Что значит "обратиться за переменными"? Вы хотите, чтобы класс-родитель обратился к членам класса-потомка? А откуда он вообще может о них знать? ЗАГС'а в C++ нет, родитель о потомках ничего не знает...

Comment: Нет, такое не сработает. Класс-предок не должен ничего знать о потомках.

Comment: Давайте начнем с вопросов архитектуры: что базовый класс с этими данными будет делать?

Comment: Что этот родитель должен будет сделать, если я от него отнаследуюсь, а переменные эти ваши не определю? =)

Comment: Можете сделать абстрактный метод для получения нужных данных и вызывать его.

Comment: Суть вопроса с самого леса. Есть вирт. класс TFigure который является родителем для классов-потомков TRectangle и TTriangle. Нужно реализовать 2 метода. Move() отвечающий за движение фигуры и IsIntersect который определяет пересекаются ли фигуры. TFigure по большому счёту пустой и содержит лишь 2 Public переменных отвечающие за шаг движения по x и y. Нужно описать метод IsIntersect, я решил, что это лучше сделать в родителе. В него надо получить координаты точек фигур из Trectangle и TTriangle для последующей обработки через блок условий. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если можно, то опишите пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: Всю дополнительную информацию желательно размещать в самом вопросе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заведите в классе `TFigure` чисто виртуальный (абстрактный) метод, возвращающий координаты точки по индексу, и имплементируйте (воплотите?) его в наследниках `TRectangle` и `TTriangle`.

То же самое - для количества точек в фигуре.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант**

Любая фигура на плоскости может быть выражена как совокупность кривых, либо отрезков, по факту, вырожденных кривых. Заведите в базовом классе "контейнер" для хранения этого, пусть std::vector.

Кривые (элемент контейнера) можно описать тройкой std::tuple, где первое и второе значение кортежа - область определения функции, третье значение - символьное представление функции.

Для того, чтобы найти все точки пересечения одной фигуры с другой - нужно попарно проанализировать отрезки сравниваемых фигур.

Основную трудность в данном подходе будет представлять парсинг текстовых формул для последующего их использования. И тем не менее, уверен, это окупится в дальнейшем. На примере школьной программы, пересечение двух отрезков:

```
y=0.5x+0.5
у=-3x-10
```

[Получаем](http://umath.ru/calc/graph/?&func=0.5x+0.5;%20-3x-10;) `x=-3`, `у=-1`

Плюс: избавляемся от "растрового" представления фигур, а это и избавление от избыточности данных, и времени на их обработку. Минус: сложность кодирования математической обработки.

Comment: Конечно это хороший ответ, но не на этот вопрос. Мне надо обратиться к членам класса из родителя. Я ни черта не понимаю как это сделать. Понятное дело что вдруг откуда не возмись ниоткуда не взялось, а потому я и ищу те самые волшебные слова которые опишут мне переменные в классе родителе, ибо я не совсем вдупляю как их там описать. Хотя киберфорум подсказывает использовать сигналы или getеры и setеры. Но мне по-моему будет проще просто описать в родителе эти переменные а потом к ним обратиться из потомков. Хотя по-моему это "тех же щей да гуще влей"

Comment: "Родитель" о потомках, как писали выше, знать не знает. Сколько тех потомков еще будет. Как вариант, объявить в родительском классе какое-то хранилище, чтобы в потомках мочь его заполнять/дополнять. Вариант не самый лучший - но возможный `std::map<std::string,std::any>`. Храните что угодно и когда угодно.

Comment: Можно, пожалуй... Я в принципе пошёл иным путём. В родителе определил переменные члены для всех и вся а потом из потомков их вызвал. Какая разница где они объявлены в этом случае? в самом классе или в родителе? Никакой(как я понимаю) Единственное что я понял, что метод IsIntersect надо сделать виртуальным а потом его ВНЕЗАПНО переопределить в потомках. 
Завтра иду на паралимпиаду по программированию...

Comment: Этот подход называют "создание класса-Бога")) Это типичная ошибка параолимпийцев))